# Find which file creates a certain html string in php

Tags: php, joomla

I'm as green as they come as regards to PHP language. Now I took upon the task to start learning PHP and Joomla.

Here's where I get stuck all the time:
I have a certain piece of html that I need to change, for example I need to remove a class from a tag. By using inspect element in Chrome I can find the piece of code and I can even test-change it right there in Chrome and have it do what I need.

But how do I move from there into locating this same piece of html in the Joomla template? Do I need to manually browse trough each file and search for the string or is there a smarter way of finding out what file is responsible for inserting that html string into the site?

Comment: You can search across files using a grep like tool. Many IDEs and editors do that as well

Comment: do some research on joomla templates\themes

Comment: Notepad++ can "search in files": http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this if to do a template override.

You class is coming from a module so you will need to override the layout of the module. It's very simple. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) on how to do it.

In your template folder, there should be a folder called "html". If not, create one.
Once done, create a new folder which is the same name as your module folder, so it should be something like **mod_art-box**. Then in the root of your Joomla site, go to **modules/mod_art-box/tmpl** and copy the default.php from there to the folder you created before. Then open the file, search for the class and remove it.

The reason I suggest doing a template override is because if the extension or Joomla itself is updated, then it will override your changes, making you have to do it again. Template overrides are not overridden.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! The address is www.manausforum/tammen/ and I need to change a class from the left sidebar menu called "art-box art-block_menu" to "art-box art-block"

Comment: One question about the template override suggestion: would this problem also be solved if I just edited my template package locally and then uploaded it as a new template? Wouldn't that change then stick?

Comment: It's not coming from the template. It's coming from the module. I will update my answer

Comment: @Sonypackman - I have updated my answer. Should you still need help, let me know ;)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful to me and thank you for your kindness towards a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

From PHP itself, there is no "simple" way to do it (I've been pestering a few people to allow overloading of `echo` - so you could track down which line echoed what without having to completely refactor everything, which would be very handy when dealing with legacy code). Joomla probably has a templating system worth its salt, so you should ideally tap into this.

If you've got some time, dig out how a template/file is rendered in joomla, and see if there is a function that is used to perform the output all the time - doesn't matter if it doesn't do the final output - and piggyback a tracking function of some sort to it. This will allow you to follow the output as it is done.

There's no better, generic solution, sadly. If you have some code to display, I might be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Okay, this was what I was kind of expecting and it answers my question that no smart "backtracking" is possible with PHP. I guess my best shot is doing a text string search from the local copy of my joomla template folder.

Answer (score 0):

The html on any page should be generated by the layout file for the view for that page, the layout files of the module for that page, or occasionally from a content plugin layout. I guess some can also come from the modules file in a template if it is creating some kind of complex module chrome. Some basic html (like the body and head tags) would be in the template index but a template in general should not be taking much responsibility for html except for layout overrides beyond setting up the main regions of the page and assigning classes to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /joomla-root -name *.php -exec grep -l 'your search string' {} \;
```

I find myself doing this all the time. it's not instantaneous, but it's much faster than manually checking all likely override files, template files, modules, components, plugins, etc.